# The Lie algebra of gradient vector fields

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Assume that  $M$ is  a  differentiable  manifold. Is there  a Riemannian  metric  on $M$  such that the  space  of all  gradient  vector  fields on $M$ would  be  closed under the  Lie  bracket?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $M$ is the circle $S^1$ there is not such metric. Indeed, any Riemannian metric on $S^1$ is isometric to the one induced on a circle of radious $r$ of the plane centered at some point.  Then take the angular "coordinate" $\theta$ and the functions $\cos(\theta)$ and $\sin(\theta)$ and check that the Lie bracket of their gradients is not a gradient.

Comment: Thank  you  for  your  answer. Since the  Lie  bracket is  a  non vanishing  vector  field. yes?

Comment: yes indeed : functions on compact manifolds have critical points.