# Lie algebra of Gradient vector fields(2)

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Motivated  [by this  question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/266083/the-lie-algebra-of-gradient-vector-fields/266087?noredirect=1#comment656718_266087), is  there a  $n$  dimensional   Riemannian  manfold $M$, $n>1$  such that the  space  of all gradient vector  fields is  a  Lie  algebra under the usual Lie  bracket of  vector  fields.

For  $n=1$ there is  an  example  and  therev  is  a  no-example: The  example  is  the  real  line  and  the  counter  example  is  $S^1$.

Comment: You can easily adapt the example for $S^1$ when $M$ has dimension $> 1$. Here is the sketch: take any point $p \in M$ put polar coordinates in $T_pM$ such that $\theta$ is one angular coordinate and compose with the exponential map at $p$ to get a local chart near $p$. Then consider the functions $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ and get a contradiction by observing the behaviour of the Lie bracket of their gradients on a circle with parameter $\theta$.

Comment: @Holonomia  May  I  ask you  to elaborate  your  comment  in the  form of  an answer.. Thank  you.

Comment: Which class of functions are you allowing here? If you allow all $C^\infty$ functions, then this can be checked locally and is impossible for $n > 1$. If you require the functions to be algebraic, the answer can be more complex.

Comment: @user44191  I consider  smooth  functions. But the  metric  is  arbitrary. For  arbitrary  metric, why is it  impossible, locally?)n>1)

Comment: I'm not at a computer, so it would be hard to write it out fully, but the idea is that gradients have to satisfy certain differential conditions (corresponding to the fact that the exterior derivative squares to 0) that Lie brackets of gradients don't. That can be used to show that given a point $p_0$, a tangent vector $\vec{v} \in T_{p_0}$, and an element of $T^2_{p_0}$, there are some functions $f, g$ which give a gradient-bracket that matches those at $p_0$, while a gradient must satisfy certain conditions on the last part.

Answer (score 4):

Let $(M^n,g)$ $n>1$ a Riemannian manifold and let $i: S^1 \to M$ a embedding of $S^1$ (it is easy to see that there are lots of such embeddings, of course here you use $n>1$...). Then take a tubular neighborhood of $i(S^1)$ as explained in Theorem 1 here:

http://montgomery.math.ucsc.edu/classes/mfds/normalbundle.pdf

Then use the coordinate $\theta$ on $i(S^1)$ and $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_{n-1}$ for the normal directions in the tubular neighborhood. Now the functions $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ are defined on the tubular neighborhood (they do not depend upon $x_1,\cdots,x_{n-1}$). Now compute the gradient of $\sin(\theta)$ and $\cos(\theta)$ and get the same contradiction as in the question you posted before.

Comment: I'm not so sure that gets the same contradiction as before; the extra dimensions can add some interesting interactions to the Lie bracket. Why would the Lie bracket necessarily have a nonzero loop integral?

Comment: Just compute the gradients and see that the bracket of the gradients restricted to $i(S^1)$  is the vector field $\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}$. Now you should see the nonzero loop integral .  Should I edit my answer and add this last few lines?

Comment: No; I think I see what I was missing. I missed the Riemannian part of the link for tubular neighborhood, and missed that the $x_i$ would be orthogonal to the circle.

Comment: @Holonomia  Thank  you  very  much  for  your  very interesting  answer.What  can  be  said about the  Lie  algebra  generated  by Gradient  vec. fields? Please see my  comment to the  other  answer.

Comment: @Holonomia  It  is  difficult to  choose  one  answer to  accept. Each  answer  has  its own interesting  point. Thank  you  again for  your  answer. http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1491/why-i-can-not-accept-two-answers-on-the-same-my-question-simultaneously

Answer (score 2):

Expanding on my comment: I will show that even looking only locally, this is impossible for dimension $n > 1$.

Define $\pi: TM \rightarrow T^*M$ as the "lowering the index" operator, taking a vector field $X \in TM$ to the covector field $\alpha \in T^*M$, where $\alpha(Y) = \langle X, Y\rangle$ for any vector field $Y$. This operator $\pi$ induces a natural linear operator from $\Gamma(TM)$ to $\Gamma (T^{*}  (M)$. We again use  $\pi$ to  denote this  induced operator. For the sake of notation, define $\{f, g\} = \langle \nabla f, \nabla g \rangle = (\nabla f)(g) = (\nabla g)(f)$

By definition, $\nabla f = \pi^{-1}(df)$. Therefore, for any gradient, we will have that $d(\pi(\nabla f)) = d(df) = 0$. We therefore only need to show that there are $f, g$ with $d(\pi([\nabla f, \nabla g])) \neq 0$. Note that this is in fact an if-and-only-if if we work locally.

Because the metric is nondegenerate, we can check what happens for vector fields that are gradients. We'll contract with one gradient at a time.

$\iota_{\nabla h}(d(\pi([\nabla f, \nabla g]))) = \mathcal{L}_{\nabla h}(\pi([\nabla f, \nabla g])) - d(\pi([\nabla f, \nabla g])(\nabla h))$

The second term is equal to $d(\langle [\nabla f, \nabla g], \nabla h \rangle)$. By the definition of $\nabla h$, this is equal to $d(\{f, \{g, h\}\} - \{g, \{f, h\}\})$.

$\iota_{\nabla j} \iota_{\nabla h}(d(\pi([\nabla f,\nabla g]))) = \iota_{\nabla j}(\mathcal{L}_{\nabla h}(\pi([\nabla f, \nabla g])) - d(\{f, \{g, h\}\} - \{g, \{f, h\}\}))$

$= \mathcal{L}_{\nabla h}(\pi([\nabla f, \nabla g])(\nabla j)) - \iota_{\mathcal{L}_{\nabla h}(\nabla j)}(\pi([\nabla f, \nabla g])) - \{j, \{f, \{g, h\}\}\} + \{j, \{g, \{f, h\}\}\}$

$= - \langle [\nabla f, \nabla g], [\nabla h, \nabla j]\rangle + \{h, \{f, \{g, j\}\}\} - \{h, \{g, \{f, j\}\}\} - \{j, \{f, \{g, h\}\}\} + \{j, \{g, \{f, h\}\}\}$

So we want to check if this is true for every $f, g, h, j$:

$\langle [\nabla f, \nabla g], [\nabla h, \nabla j]\rangle = \{h, \{f, \{g, j\}\}\} - \{h, \{g, \{f, j\}\}\} - \{j, \{f, \{g, h\}\}\} + \{j, \{g, \{f, h\}\}\}$

Call the left side $A(f, g, h, j)$ and the right side $B(f, g, h, j)$. Assume that $A(f, g, h, j) = B(f, g, h, j)$ for all $f, g, h, j$. Then $A(f, g g', h, j) - g A(f, g', h, j) - g' A(f, g, h, j) = B(f, g g', h, j) - g B(f, g', h, j) - g' B(f, g, h, j)$.

A quick calculation shows that $A(f, g g', h, j) - g A(f, g', h, j) - g' A(f, g, h, j) = \{f, g\} \{h, \{j, g'\}\} - \{f, g\} \{j, \{h, g'\}\} + \{f, g'\} \{h, \{j, g\}\} - \{f, g'\} \{j, \{h, g\}\}$.

On the other hand, $B(f, g g', h, j) - g B(f, g', h, j) - g' B(f, g, h, j) = \{f, g\} \{h, \{g', j\}\} + \{h, g\} \{f, \{g', j\}\} + \{g, j\} \{h, \{f, g'\}\} + \{f, g'\} \{h, \{g, j\}\} + \{h, g'\} \{f, \{g, j\}\} + \{g', j\} \{h, \{f, g\}\} - \{h, g\} \{g', \{f, j\}\} - \{h, g'\} \{g, \{f, j\}\} - (\{f, g\} \{j, \{g', h\}\} + \{j, g\} \{f, \{g', h\}\} + \{g, h\} \{j, \{f, g'\}\} + \{f, g'\} \{j, \{g, h\}\} + \{j, g'\} \{f, \{g, h\}\} + \{g', h\} \{j, \{f, g\}\} - \{j, g\} \{g', \{f, h\}\} - \{j, g'\} \{g, \{f, h\}\})$

So we want to check whether:

$\{h, g\}(- \{g', \{f, j\}\} - \{j, \{f, g'\}\} + \{f, \{g', j\}\}) + \{j, g\}(\{g', \{f, h\}\} + \{h, \{f, g'\}\} - \{f, \{g', h\}\}) + \{h, g'\}(- \{g, \{f, j\}\} - \{j, \{f, g\}\} + \{f, \{g, j\}\}) + \{j, g'\}(\{g, \{f, h\}\} + \{h, \{f, g\}\} - \{f, \{g, h\}\}) = 0$.

Using a similar trick by splitting $f$ to $f f'$, we get:

$2 \{h, g\}\{g', f\}\{f', j\} + \text{similar terms} = 0$, where "similar terms" refers to all terms gotten by switching g and g', switching f and f', and switching h and j and negating.

We've finally made it to a pointwise condition - which means that we only need to check this on a vector space with the standard metric. And it is false; take $h = g = g' = f = x, f' = j = y$. More generally, if we let $h, g, g', f, f', j = a_i x + b_i y$, the equation is:

$(a_1 a_2 + b_1 b_2)(a_3 a_4 + b_3 b_4)(a_5 a_6 + b_5 b_6) + \text{similar terms} = 0$.

The terms consisting of just $a$ or just $b$ cancel out; the only terms left either have 4 $a$s and 2 $b$s or vice versa. It's not hard to see that these terms can't cancel - the two $b$s (or the two $a$s) must remain together, which gives a unique product it can come from.

To summarize: We took the question, extracted a differential condition from it, extracted a pointwise condition from the differential condition, and showed that the pointwise condition could not be satisfied in dimension > 1.

ETA: To give a more explicit answer: choose coordinates $x, y$. Then:

$d(\pi([\nabla x^2, \nabla xy])) = d(\pi([2x \nabla x, x \nabla y + y \nabla x])) = d(\pi(2x \nabla y - 2y \nabla x + 2x^2 [\nabla x, \nabla y]))$

$= d(2x dy - 2y dx + 2x^2 [\nabla x, \nabla y]) = 4 dx \wedge dy + 4x dx \wedge \pi([\nabla x, \nabla y]) + 2x^2 d(\pi([\nabla x, \nabla y]))$

Just by checking at 0, we can see that this is nonzero - so $d(\pi([\nabla x^2, \nabla xy]))$ must be nonzero - so as long as $dx$ and $dy$ are linearly independent at some point where $x = 0$ (hence the need for $n > 1$), then at that point, $[\nabla x^2, \nabla xy]$ is not a gradient.

Comment: I really thank you  very  much for your  very interesting  answer.  As  we  see, the  coefficient  $g_{ij}$ of  metric does not  play  a  crucial role  in your  interesting answer. So   this  situation is  a  vague motivation for  the  question "Does  the  Lie  algebra  structure  of the  Lie  subalgebra  generated  by  gradient  vector  fields depend  on a  chosen Riemannian metric"? What is a description of the  Lie  algebra  generated  by  Gradient  vector  fields  corresponding  to  a  given metric? Thanks again  for  your help.

Comment: It  is  difficult to  choose  one  answer to  accept. Each  answer  has  its own interesting  point. Thank  you  again for  your  answer. http://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/1491/why-i-can-not-accept-two-answers-on-the-same-my-question-simultaneously